# Get posts only from those who follow you back in flask app with sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that uses a blend of sqlalchemy (ORM) and flask sqlalchemy.

I have a User model, a Post model, and a followers table as follows:

```
from app import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class User(UserMixin, db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    followed = db.relationship('User', secondary=followers,
                               primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
                               secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
                               backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic') # many to many relationship with other Users
    posts = relationship('Post') # one to many relationship with posts
    # ...

class Post(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    #...

followers= db.Table('followers',
                       db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
                       db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
                       )
```

**My question is**  how to query the Post table/model so that it returns only posts written by users that follow you back (i.e. friends). 
The [flask mega tutorial by Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-viii-followers) (which these models are based off of) uses the following sqlalchemy query to accomplish something similar to what I'm after.

```
def followed_posts(self):
        return Post.query.join(
            followers, (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)).filter(
                followers.c.follower_id == self.id).order_by(
                    Post.timestamp.desc())
```

I've been trying to modify the above query so that the Post table joins only with the subset of followers, characterized by if (a,b) in followers, then (b,a) in followers. I am just not sure how to implement this.

Any help would be appreciated. Also if anyone has a recommendation for a guide that goes over more 'advanced' sqlalchemy queries like the one above without a ton of pure SQL prerequisite knowledge please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you just switch the `followed_id` and `follower_id` in the `def followed_posts(self): ...` query from Miguels's case: he lists the posts of those you follows, so the inverse will be the posts of those who follow you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @van. that's closer to what i'm after than the original query. but in my case I still need to check that both users follow each other.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
def get_friend_posts():
    return Post.query.filter(Post.user_id.in_([f.id for f in self.followed if f.is_following(self)]))

# helper function
def is_following(self, user):
        return self.followed.filter(followers.c.followed_id == user.id).count() > 0
```

Comment: I do not think this is the most efficient way, as you will be performing many SQL queries to get the result you want. Please see my answer for 1-query options.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute and get what you want in one query, the following two options should produce the same result, but are quite different in being `pythonic` or `SQL-ic`.

**Option-1:**
I find this to be quite `pythonic` as the `Poster.followed.any(...)` reads as "where one of the followers is *me*.". But the SQL it produces is a bit "ugly", although it gets the job done:

```
    def followed_posts__elegant_any(self):
        user_id = self.id
        Poster = aliased(User, name="poster")
        return (
            object_session(self)
            .query(Post)
            .join(Poster, Post.user)
            .filter(Poster.followed.any(User.id == user_id))
            .filter(Poster.followers.any(User.id == user_id))
            .order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())
        )
```

**Option-2:**

This is much more straightforward and is expressed in very "pure" SQL logic:

- create aliases so that can join on `followers` table twice
- perform join twice to ensure that the relationship between current user and "Poster" are both ways. The join itself is not really used for anything else, but filtering:

```
def followed_posts__optimal_join(self):
    user_id = self.id
    f1 = aliased(followers)
    f2 = aliased(followers)
    return (
        object_session(self)
        .query(Post)
        .join(User, Post.user)
        .join(f1, and_(User.id == f1.c.follower_id, f1.c.followed_id == user_id))
        .join(f2, and_(User.id == f2.c.followed_id, f2.c.follower_id == user_id))
        .order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())
    )
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write up these solutions. both queries work beautifully and were exactly what I had in mind! i just had to change `Post.user ` to `User.query.filter_by(id=Post.user_id)` in the first join. cheers my friend.